# Pyramid Python Activity-Based Checks

Tags: python, authorization, pyramid

A while back I asked a question about Authentication (Authorization was also implied). That question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792769/user-authentication-in-pyramid).

As systems I've worked on have grown and as customer needs have come up in unexpected ways I've found role/permission-based authorization unable to grow/adapt well.

I recently came across an interesting article regarding [activity-based authorization vs role-based authorization](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/05/24/dont-do-role-based-authorization-checks-do-activity-based-checks/), making a strong argument for activity-based authorization.

Does anyone know of any activity-based libraries that would plug'n'play well with Pyramid (preferably Python 3 compatible)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at veryfay for a early implementation of a Scala activity authorisation framework https://github.com/florinn/veryfay-python/blob/master/README.md